# Reporting a YouTube Video through API from Desktop Application

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, desktop-application, google-api-dotnet-client

I am currently working on a desktop application that requires the ability to report inappropriate YouTube videos using the YouTube API. Although I have reviewed the YouTube API documentation, I'm encountering challenges in understanding how to implement the process of programmatically reporting a video. I have come across an example code in a different programming language, but I'm struggling to locate an equivalent solution in C#.

I have referred to the YouTube API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/reportAbuse?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22videoId%22%3A%22BgToyjyO1CU%22%7D%7D&apix=true), specifically the videos.reportAbuse endpoint, which seems to provide the functionality I need. However, the code example provided is in a different programming language, and I'm unable to find a similar example in C#.

How do I implement the `reportAbuse` endpoint in C#?

```
string credentialsPath = "googlefile.json";

// Scopes for YouTube API
string[] scopes = { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl };

// Load the credentials file
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(credentialsPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(scopes);
}

// Initialize the YouTube API service with OAuth2 credentials
var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "My Project 55555"
});

// Video ID you want to report
string videoId = "xxxxx";

// Create the abuse report snippet
var abuseReport = new VideoAbuseReport();
abuseReport.VideoId = videoId;
abuseReport.ReasonId = "spam"; // You need to find the appropriate reason ID

// Submit the report
var reportRequest = youtubeService.Videos.ReportAbuse(abuseReport);
var response = reportRequest.Execute();
```

Now I am using YouTubeService and getting this error ":

> 'Error creating credential from JSON or JSON parameters. Unrecognized credential type .'"

I have downloaded the GoogleCredential json file.

Comment: Just use [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0) and give it all the needed details like URL, headers, etc. What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Are you trying to create a program that mass reports youtube videos? Why?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I am unable to run the javascript version, what should I insert in "onBehalfOfContentOwner" and yes I tried httpClient, let me edit the question

Comment: @John I'm actually interested in developing a C# browser for my kids. This browser would allow my kids to browse, and I would have the ability to review multiple videos and report them in bulk. Currently, I have to individually report videos on YouTube. While I'm aware of the safe mode on YouTube, it doesn't provide sufficient control

Comment: @Ahmed Ah that's a lot more wholesome use case than I initially thought! I hope it goes well. Like Good Night said, this API works via web requests, so you'll need to use a `HttpClient` to access it directly. Google also have a API for C# that may be of some help if you want to use those instead - there are some examples of it being used for search here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#search_by_keyword

Comment: I've removed the `[winforms]` tag because this question isn't about Windows Forms. Regarding your question: you presumably need to use OAuth to obtain a short-lived access token to use with the API (that's my understanding based on reading the message).

Comment: Now I am using YouTubeService and getting this error ": 'Error creating credential from JSON or JSON parameters. Unrecognized credential type .'"
I have downloaded the GoogleCredential json file.

Comment: Since you asked in the answer's comments: your video was probably downvoted, because you initially didn't show us what you've tried. You need to almost always add the actual code that is making problems to your question, so people can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started its my auth coded for YouTube.  Just change the scope.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

const string pathToKeyFile = @"C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\credentials.json";

const string videoPath = "";

// scope of authorization needed from the user
var scopes = new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube };

// file to upload
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile(pathToKeyFile).Secrets,
    scopes,
    "test",
    CancellationToken.None).Result;

// Create the  Youtube service.
var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Daimto Youtube upload Quickstart"
});
```

## Reasons list

Remember you need to grab the Abuse reason. from [videoAbuseReportReasons list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoAbuseReportReasons/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%7D)

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#videoAbuseReportReason",
      "etag": "95t7kDR9fIaw7_qtu0LG4hkmfRI",
      "id": "N",
      "snippet": {
        "label": "Sex or nudity"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#videoAbuseReportReason",
      "etag": "rqXGFg-vDu_OHLwyfWecptaHny0",
      "id": "V",
      "snippet": {
        "label": "Violent, hateful, or dangerous",
        "secondaryReasons": [
          {
            "id": "35",
            "label": "Promotes violence or hatred"
          },
          {
            "id": "38",
            "label": "Suicide or self injury"
          },
          {
            "id": "39",
            "label": "Pharmaceutical or drug abuse"
          },
          {
            "id": "41",
            "label": "Graphic violence"
          },
          {
            "id": "43",
            "label": "Weapons"
          },
          {
            "id": "44",
            "label": "Digital security"
          },
          {
            "id": "40",
            "label": "Other violent, hateful, or dangerous acts"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#videoAbuseReportReason",
      "etag": "orwADIA7_Uir4yYCOkr8aUPgKBc",
      "id": "C",
      "snippet": {
        "label": "Child abuse"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#videoAbuseReportReason",
      "etag": "_C6P5gRJeQg_3tZrpcwodoPmhMs",
      "id": "M",
      "snippet": {
        "label": "Medical misinformation"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#videoAbuseReportReason",
      "etag": "utqOkIhK33vDq9A64XcflehWnzg",
      "id": "E",
      "snippet": {
        "label": "Violent extremism"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#videoAbuseReportReason",
      "etag": "HWSFj3k4pMpiUDkp419CS3Ijkhc",
      "id": "H",
      "snippet": {
        "label": "Harassment or bullying"
      }
    }
  ],
  "kind": "youtube#videoAbuseReportReasonListResponse",
  "etag": "NHfccB0wL0fbMxeiDWA-XX_3NnY"
}
```

## note

This code will require [installed app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwqJcyLQSSQ) credentials file which has YouTube api enabled under library.

## User credential storage.

GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker by default stores the users credentials in the %appData% folder on the machine its running on denoted by the user name which in the code above is set to "test".

If you want another user to be able to login then you should just change the "test" to something else and it will prompt the new user.

Comment: Everything working perfect and Now my code is able to report a video. But when I see the reporting history in youtube is shows black reason. see this following screenshot https://snipboard.io/YvqnZ2.jpg. I use this reason ID {
      "kind": "youtube#videoAbuseReportReason",
      "etag": "mrvr8uttlB9V0EZ3-DreJrBciF0",
      "id": "M"
    },

Comment: @Ahmed I believe your post was voted down because when it was posted it had the wrong tags and it didn't contain any code, which is one of the main requirements for a good SO question. Once it was edited to include your code and more details it improved the question, so it stopped getting downvoted and it is now on a positive score

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo thanks for the Reason List, it is working perfect now. I have another question to ask but StackOverflow showing "It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!" let me ask here.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo As we can report the video by clicking the "Report" button on the video itself, which triggers an API call from the client side along with specific headers. Are we able to replicate this API call, along with the same headers, using POSTman? I'm considering creating a Google extension that will facilitate reporting videos through an Ajax call within the YouTube platform.

Comment: I have an old video on how to configure postman for google oauth2 have a look https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjCauMywU2Q

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I apologize for any confusion in my previous message. To clarify, when a regular user clicks on the 'Report' button on a YouTube video and selects a reason for reporting it, an API call is triggered, which we can monitor in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools. My objective is to utilize that API while including the users' headers. My aim is to enable video reporting using the user's email address, rather than relying on my OAuth2 credentials, as multiple users will be using the same browser. P.S I will create google extension for it to inject the javascipt.

Comment: Check my update on user credentials.   as for your google extension remember this is a desktop app and not a web app.